# .htaccess - Hiding folders with files

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, directory

So, like everyone, my website is getting targeted by people wanting all the code. I setup a htaccess file which shows nothing when you enter domain.com/images BUT if the user goes to domain.com/images/logo.png the logo image will then appear. A person is doing this to obtain the CSS and JS.

Anyone know how I can hide both the folder AND the files inside so no matter what they cannot access stuff they shouldn't?

Thanks!!

Comment: Your CSS and JS is part of rendered website. It will appear when the page is loaded.

Comment: This is impossible technically, unless you want the CSS and JS not to be loaded to the browser, period.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the following inside your .htaccess to prevent people from accessing the directory containing this .htaccess file, sub director(ies) of it and all files inside them:

```
deny from all
```

But please be aware doing this to CSS and images files will prevent the browser from accessing them and displaying them to the visitor.

If you want to still display them on the website but prevent direct access to the files, you can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

This will prevent accessing gif and jpg files for example if there is no HTTP referer coming in (i.e. being accessed from a linked page).

Comment: What will happen if the files are linked with web page, and user tries to load page?

Comment: They will not be displayed. No one can access them.

Comment: Right, then there are many methods available to protect files, instead of using .htaccess. Like, password protected directory. I am not sure, but if his files are linked with page then he cannot use this method, or any method.